# Can't connect to my public IP from other machine in same local network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have recently set up port forwarding on my router so that it forwards incoming traffic at port `48888` to my laptop:

[image: port mapping]

I have set up static DCHP for my laptop so that it always has the same local IP, i.e. `192.168.0.35`. From now on I'll use `80.222.77.111` to refer to my public IP (though it isn't exactly this), i.e. the router's public IP.

To check that this was working, I started listening to incoming traffic on this laptop with `netcat`:

```bsh
nc -kl 48888
```

(using the `nc` package on Cygwin). I then started the mobile hotspot on my phone, and connected a second laptop to that; from there, I opened a terminal and used netcat again to connect to the host through the public IP:

```bsh
nc 80.222.77.111 48888
```

This connected successfully and I was able to send messages back and forth.

However, when both computers are connected to the same local network (specifically connected to the same router via WiFi), this doesn't work. After starting `nc -kl 48888` on the host, running `nc 80.222.77.111 48888` on the other machine just hangs for a couple of seconds and then returns, with no output. Upon inspection, the exit code seemed to be `1`. Similarly, running the following python script on the client machine

```python
import socket


HOST = "80.222.77.111"
PORT = 48_888

with socket.socket() as s:
    print(f"Trying to connect to {HOST}:{PORT} ...")
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print("Successfully connected")
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        if not msg: break
        print("From server:", msg)
        msg = input("Client, enter message: ")
        if not msg: break
        s.send(bytes(msg + "\n", encoding="ASCII"))
```

results in

```
Trying to connect to 80.222.77.111:48888 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 14, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

This is weird, why would I be able to connect from outside but not from inside?

Furthermore, I also tried connecting directly to the local IP from the same network, i.e.

```bsh
nc 192.168.0.35 48888
```

This *did* work.

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a loopback connection as follows:

```
local -> router -> internet > router > local
```

Most consumer routers only implement request-answer algorithms and
are not programmed to handle a case where the answer is actually another request.
Meaning that it implements "request-answer" rather than "request-request-answer-answer".

Some routers prevent loopback connections as a security feature.
Most consumer-grade routers don't have any prohibition against it, it just doesn't work.

You may login to your router's administration page and look for anything about
permitting loopback connections (or similar).
If nothing is found, then the router is just not suitable.
Flashing a more advanced firmware such as DD-WRT might help (but that's a chancy
operation).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! You mention some routers prevent this for security. What would the security implications be of enabling such a loopback connection?

Comment: My guess would be that it's for preventing a virus from diverting an internet request to the virus itself locally, so it can disguise itself as that website. But there may be other explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like either you have windows defender blocking your request or you may have an anti-virus blocking it. So just for the sake of testing, try disabling it or adding it to the exception list and that should help you confirm what's the problem. Once you know the cause, you will be able to make it work.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I have no AV and I have added a rule to the firewall (and even tried disabling it). I think what's happening what David said in the comments.