# How does port forwarding work

Tags: router, port-forwarding, web-hosting

I have `192.168.0.3` on LAN, and ran on my pc ASP NET app on this IP and port 80. It works well on LAN, when I type `192.168.0.3:80`, nothing exciting.

But I wanted to do port forwarding. So on my router, in port forwarding section, I setted up IP to `192.168.0.3` and port range to 80-80. I selected TCP as a protocol.

I don't know if I understand well port forwarding, but I thought that if now I type my public IP address along with port, then I would get response from my ASP NET app.

But it occured that doesn't work like this. I even completely disabled firewall on my PC (Windows).

So my question is why it doesn't work, and did I misunderstand port forwarding?

Comment: Take a look at the existing threads about "NAT hairpin" or "NAT loopback" on this site. It's a common topic – port forwarding due to its design can't reliably work when you're on the same network as the "forwarded to" server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to my public IP from other machine in same local network](https://superuser.com/questions/1611424/cant-connect-to-my-public-ip-from-other-machine-in-same-local-network)

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers. So as I understand, the server cannot be in the same network in which router is (and this is due to NAT)? So I need in my LAN something like router-switch-server? And provided question says about connecting "from other machine in same local network", but I cannot do it even from a different, remote network.

Comment: Being unable to access from a different network is usually a completely different issue (e.g. the CGNAT problem; how did you determine your own public IP address?)

Comment: yeah you can't test your port forwarding from within your LAN. you can check the port https://canyouseeme.org/ if you want to see if the port is accessible to external users, but if you want to actually test the app, you'll have to go to a coffee shop or whatever.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I just went to router admin page to "WAN status". If you meant the public address from different network than router, I don't know it, but it wasn't the same address, as it was address of my friend several km away.

Comment: 1. how do you know your friends IP address? have you set up a vpn connection with them or something? 2. what IP do you get when you google "whats my IP"? that will be your public IP address (unless you have a VPN to your friends network, and are sending all your traffic through it and out his connection). 3. if you use canyouseeme with that IP address does it see port 80 as open?

Comment: 1. I don't know, but do I need to? I don't have VPN connection, just wanted to have connection over Internet. 2. The IP is the same as the IP in "WAN Status" at router page. 3. It says that it couldn't see my service. I read there that ISP can block 80 port, so I setted UP 81-82 and still doesnt work.

Comment: if you indeed have the same public IP as your friend (and you don't have a VPN to their network), it is likely that your ISP is sharing a pool of public IPs amongst its subscribers (basically the CGNAT scenario). In that case you will not be able to create publicly available resources using only port forwarding. you may be able to buy a static IP from  your ISP, or you can look into alternatives like VPN services, reverse-tunneling, etc.

Comment: It must be different IP. Even he use different ISP.